# Relative Import Confuses me

Tags: python, relative-import

This is a test directory.

```
Main_folder
|-- in_root.py
|-- 1stlayer
   |-- 1stlayer.py
```

So I want to import some functions from in_root.py in 1stlayer.py.
I tried `from ..in_root import *` but it gave me the error, 'attempted relative import with no known parent package'.
Please anyone help, I am always stuck with higher level relative imports in my projects.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)

Answer (score -1):

This link is might be the one you are looking for!

Also `PYTHONPATH` might be helpful! It is an enviromental variable which can contain the directory where your script is.

`PYTHONPATH = PATH/libs/`

- libs
  | lib.py
- project
  | project.py

from project.py:

`import lib.py`

A brief explanation: https://bic-berkeley.github.io/psych-214-fall-2016/using_pythonpath.html